# Rails 3.1.3 Production Stylesheets not compiling consistently with Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, stylesheet, spree

I have a rails app which compiles my stylesheets correctly in development. In production however, it doesn't.

I've tried to make the configuration values the same for my production config by setting

```
config.assets.compress = false

config.assets.compile = false

config.assets.digest = true

config.assets.debug = true
```

This does almost everything, it doesn't display the comments about where the css was compiled from like it does on development, and I haven't figured out how to enable that. My first question is how would I enable that in production for debugging?

Next - specificially using Spree 0.70.2, and what happens is in development the stylesheets from the gem are compiled. In production, they're being ignored. What could be the cause of this?

Is there a way to follow what's being compiled, a way to trace it (--trace when you run rake doesn't give you much relevant info)

Thanks